# Is it possible to hide the SSID of the Windows 7 soft AP

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

I know it is possible to create a sofware AP in windows 7 using command prompt:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork ...
```

But is it possible to set such a network not to broadcast its SSID?

I realize that this does not gain any security - or may even make the system more secure, but I am not asking about security here. I want to know if it is possible, through the netsh command interface, to hide the SSID.

If my client wants to hide the SSID, then I will make them aware of security implications, but in the end it is their decision.

Comment: Do you think that will make it more secure?

Comment: No, I don't. But it will be <perceived> as more secure and that's why I am researching it.

Comment: Perhaps someone might perceive it as being more secure but if so they are wrong. And anything that you configure to connect to that soft AP will be demonstrably less secure. Some good points here : http://blogs.technet.com/b/steriley/archive/2007/10/16/myth-vs-reality-wireless-ssids.aspx

Comment: Again, I realize that. My question isn't "Is it secure to do to", my question is "Is it possible to do so".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question of Goro is NOT about security.
To answer the question I'd add that when you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd815243%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you can't see any mean to hide the SSID. It's not a functionality which seems to be implemented.