# Using netsh wlan to create a hidden network

Tags: windows-10, netsh, internet-sharing

I currently use the command `netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=“someId” key=“somePassword”` in windows 10 to create a wireless network and share my cabled internet connection via wlan.

**Is there any way to make this shared connection hidden?**

**PS:** I don't care if I accomplish it with netsh commands or with any 3rd party apps, but I prefer only with commands.

---

**EDIT**

I can see now that by command it is not possible to hide SSID [in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/188644/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-ssid-of-the-windows-7-soft-ap). I wanted to know not only with commands, but if I can accomplish it with any 3rd party app. **Because of this I think this question is not duplicated.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hide the SSID of the Windows 7 soft AP](http://superuser.com/questions/188644/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-ssid-of-the-windows-7-soft-ap)